# Swift Google map in SKScene

Tags: swift, google-maps, sprite-kit, skscene, gmsmapview

I am trying to add a google Map view to a `SKScene` this is what i have so far:

```
class GoogleMapView: SKScene, GMSMapViewDelegate {

var map = GMSMapView(frame: CGRectZero)
var gmsCamera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.868, longtitude: 151.2086, zoom: 6)

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    map.delegate = self
    map.indoorEnabled = false
    map.camera = gmsCamera

    view.addSubview(map)

    }
}
```

Then I run this, the map doesn't show up!

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: shot in the dark here since i havent used google maps in ios.. maybe you should be implementing it in the viewcontroller file?